# Dynamic routes in laravel instead of manual routes

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes

I want to prevent write all route in Laravel route.php,actually i follow MVC routing like this www.example.com/controller/action/p1/p2/p3
if you have any good idea give it to me,
i wrote this

```
$controller = ucfirst(Request::segment(1));
$controller = $controller . 'Controller';
$result=App::make('indexController')->ChechIfExistController($controller);
if($result){    
        if(Request::segment(2))
            $action=Request::segment(2);
        else
            $action='index';

    if(Request::segment(5))
            Route::any('/{controller?}/{action?}/{p1?}/{p2?}/{p3?}',array('uses'=>$controller.'@'.$action));
        else if(Request::segment(4))
            Route::any('/{controller?}/{action?}/{p1?}/{p2?}',array('uses'=>$controller.'@'.$action));
        else if(Request::segment(3))
            Route::any('/{controller?}/{action?}/{p1?}',array('uses'=>$controller.'@'.$action));
        else
            Route::any('/{controller?}/{action?}',array('uses'=>$controller.'@'.$action));

}   else{
    echo '404';
    EXIT;

}
```

but i don't know how to control and check controller and action in laravel to understand if it exist or not.
i need your help.
thanks a lot.

ifound it,this code fix the problem and check if action exist or not,but i would like to do that with laravel but it seems laravel does not have any thing for checking controller and actions

```
 $controller=='Controller'?$controller='IndexController':$controller;

        $controllers=new $controller ();

        if(method_exists($controllers,$action)){...}
```

and in composer define my route,
that's all

Comment: I am not sure but `Resource Controllers` may help you.

Comment: thanks but it didnot help,if you have any example about it may help,thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

routes.php

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
]);
```

in AuthController you can do that:

```
// will be available as METHODNAME /auth/url/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}
public [methodName]Url($one, $two, $three, $four, $five)
{
   //...
}

// for example POST /auth/register
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    // ...
}

// GET /auth/login
public function getLogin()
{
    //...
}
```

it's not documented, but you can see that in sources:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src%2FIlluminate%2FRouting%2FControllerInspector.php
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src%2FIlluminate%2FRouting%2FRouter.php#L238

Comment: thanks,but how can i check controller and method exist in laravel????
e.g in address bar we have example.com/test/test2
but test as controller and test2 as an action does not exist!!
is it possible check them by laravel??

Comment: you don't need to check it, ir's router responsibility. just follow conventions above

Comment: from ControllerInspector:
"When a controller is routed using this method, we use Reflection to parse out all of the routable methods for the controller, then register each route explicitly for the developers, so reverse routing is possible."

Comment: oh, i understood, you want dynamic controller also. you can't do that with default router, i think

Comment: or any example can be helpfull

Comment: yes that right,dynamic route,how can i do that in laravel???look at my code in above

Answer (score 0):

That can be done such way:
First we have to write static routes and after that, dynamic route which uses database.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'welcome';
});

Route::get('/faq', function () {
    return 'faq';
});

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return 'about';
});

Route::get('/{slug}', function ($slug) {
    return Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();
});
```